# Power Supply rise time and configuration

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, power, usb, rise-time

Reset managment:
from [HW checklist](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/UNG/ProductDocuments/DesignChecklist/USB2517-Hardware-Design-Checklist-00004211.pdf) and [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/USB2517-USB2517i-Data-Sheet-00001598C.pdf) of USB2517 (page 48), is required a rise time for the 3V3 maximum of 400us. In our case it will be above 1ms.
In this case, is it necessary to use a reset management chip that releases it only when 3V3 is in steady state or is an RC network like the one shown in the check list sufficient? Figure 7.2

Configuration Pin CFG_SEL0/1/2 :
in the application the upstream host and Hub are always connected because physically on the same board. They are also always powered.
External “Hardware Resistor Straps” resistors are used for port configuration. In this scenario what is the right configuration for the CFG_SEL0/1/2 pins?
The LED features are not used .

Configuration NON_REM[1:0] : in the application we have 4 ports that are removable as they are connected to USB connectors that are used or not by the end user. Then there are 2 ports which in my opinion are NOT removable as they are connected to devices internal to the application, therefore once the machine is assembled they are always wired. The seventh port is not used.
Do you confirm that the correct configuration is NON_REM1 = 1, NON_REM0 = 0 ?

Comment: the linked documents are both the same and only 24 pages long.

Comment: @Andyaka, sorry fixed it now

Comment: Isn't this best asked from an Microchip FAE? We can't guess if the chip needs a reset management chip or if RC is enough if your supply takes 1ms to rise. There may be internal mechanisms in the IC that only Microchip engineers know.

Comment: @Justme, ok then let me contact Microchip. Could you help on the CFG and NON_REM pin question clarification, please?